# Beautiful soup output to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping google scholar using beautiful soup. Using below code I only get the first row on the dataframe.Need to get the three outputs row wise in the dataframe. Not sure how to go about it and I'm new to scraping. Thanks

queries = ['10.1371/journal.pone.0213627',
'10.1186/s13223-019-0377-7',
'10.1371/journal.pmed.1002751']

publications = []

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    for query in queries:
        url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=' + query + '&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&btnG=Search'
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') # or 'html.parser'
        title = soup.select_one('.gs_rt a')
        if title is None:
            title = 'No title'
            link = 'No link'
        else:  
            link = title['href']
            title = title.text
        citations = soup.select_one('[title=Cite] + a')
        if citations is None:
            citations = 'No citation count'
        else:
             citations = citations.text
       
publications.append ((title, link,citations))

df = pd.DataFrame(publications)

df
```

Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw3nX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation of `publications.append ((title, link,citations))` is wrong. Now you are only appending the last item of `queries` to `publications`, instead of every item in the for-loop. Just put `publications.append ((title, link,citations))` inside your for-loop

```
queries = ['10.1371/journal.pone.0213627', '10.1186/s13223-019-0377-7', '10.1371/journal.pmed.1002751']

publications = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    for query in queries:
        url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=' + query + '&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&btnG=Search'
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') # or 'html.parser'
        title = soup.select_one('.gs_rt a')
        if title is None:
            title = 'No title'
            link = 'No link'
        else:  
            link = title['href']
            title = title.text
        citations = soup.select_one('[title=Cite] + a')
        if citations is None:
            citations = 'No citation count'
        else:
             citations = citations.text
       
        publications.append ((title, link,citations))

df = pd.DataFrame(publications)

df
```

Comment: Indentation was the issue. It worked. Thanks...signed newbie

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code, instead of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(publications)
```

Use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"content":publications})
```

Comment: Hi @sal that's not working maybe I'm not getting it correctly

Comment: Hi, If I have understood your issue correctly you basically want all the entries from publication list to appear as rows in your dataframe under a single column right? Or you want 3 columns title, link and citations?

Answer (score 0):

indent publications.append((title, link,citations)) to make it inside the loop.